# Unable to access backend using Postman and Authorization token

Tags: django, angular, jwt

Angular 8 and Django 3. I am getting a `user_id` and `token` from django using a custom view class `CustomAuthToken`. I get a response that has a `token` and `user_id`. I am following a tutorial and want to test out the sending a custom header to django to see if the authorization works.

I am using Postman and setting the headers to `Authorization: Bearer 1a683...9e428`. When I send a GET request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/dashboard/23` I get a response
    `"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."`

My understanding is providing these headers should work? Or is there something on the client-side that decodes the header and sends it back or something?

**views.py**

```
class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                           context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
        })
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),

}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/<int:pk>', UserDashboard.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
    path(r'api-token-auth/', CustomAuthToken.as_view()),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `Token` prefix in authorization header instead of bearer:

```
Authorization: Token 1a683...9e428
```

See [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) for more details.

Comment: that definitely did it thanks so much. In the link you sent however, I dont really understand what the difference is between the two use cases `JWT` vs `Token`. One is obtaining and one is refreshing? Edit: I think i see, the `Token` is used where there is an external service looking to verify?

Comment: @ratrace123 You are welcome. As for JWT it's different type of token autorization where you don't really need to keep token in database. You can find information about it on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token